# What does this mean??? Matlab

Tags: matlab, image-processing

```
if ispc && isequal(get(hObject,'BackgroundColor'), get(0,'defaultUicontrolBackgroundColor'))
set(hObject,'BackgroundColor','white');
```

What does this code mean 
It is used for GUI on Matlab

Answer (score 5):

This is very difficult with so little context but I think I have some clue:

we start with a two part if: `ispc` is a [built in function](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ispc.html) which does it's name, it returns whether or not the computer is a PC. false on linux/mac OSx and true on PC's.

The next part uses isequal to compare two values. The first: `get(hObject,'BackgroundColor')` will get the background color of wherever the handle hObject points. The second part, gets the default background color, which from [here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/uicontrol_props.html) says "The default color is determined by system settings"

So  this code means: For the figure with handle `hObject`, if we are on a pc AND our background color is the default background color, change it to white.